# Python import enum error

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, enums, module

Having trouble using Enum. Running Python 2.7 on Linux Debian Distribution.
Installed enum package as well as enum34 package for older Python version compatibility.

When I try to import enum with this command in my python module:

```
from enum import Enum
```

I get the error:

```
from enum import Enum
ImportError: No module named enum
```

I've tried using:

```
import enum
```

and

```
import enum34
```

with no luck... Getting errors respectively:

```
ImportError: No module named enum
```

and

```
ImportError: No module named enum34
```

The way I'm trying to use Enum is:

```
class Callable_Options(Enum):
     function_callable   = 0
     help_param_callable = 1
     help_str_callable   = 2
```

But my module errors before this.

Any idea how to get Enum working?

Thanks.

EDIT:

Note that I had to change my class to inherit the object

```
class Callable_Options(IntEnum):
```

instead of

```
class Callable_Options(Enum):
```

To be able to use the attributes to index a list

Comment: did you install it with `pip`? Which python version do you use? Is the installed `enum34` module in your PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Yes I installed it using pip install. Python version 2.7 and I believe enum34 is in my Pythonpath because its in the same location as all my other modules. 

Do I need to add it specifically?

Comment: Okay, and do you use the correct python interpreter? Are you in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to find the path where `enum` gets installed. Try this:

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(<somemodule>.__file__)
print path
```

You can use `math` module for `<somemodule>` to find the path for your packages.
On Mac , usually, `path = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` 
Browse to that director and look for `enum`. 
If it is not there, find out where `pip` installs packages on your machine and add that path to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This script helped me find out that I was not adding to my PythonPath correctly. 

When I add: 
      sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages")
it runs.

Seems like I need to find out how to add to my Python Path properly. I'll up vote this when I have enough points!

Comment: Remember that `sys.path.append()` is not a permanent solution! Need to added it to `.bashrc` or `.bashrc_profile` for path to be permanent if you reboot your machine.

Comment: Yeah. I added the path to `.bashrc` and ran `source ~./bashrc` to implement the change. It wasn't adding because I didn't run the source. I can't reboot my machine because its a build server many people are on. After running the source command everything is good! Thanks @flamenco